# Vuejs get current route name and display on the menu

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm using the `vue-menu` component, and using it to toggle between different routes. After I switch to another route I want to display the current route name on the dropdown header like so:

[image]

I've tried using the life-cycle methods such as `beforeCreate , created, mounted...` etc but none of them are being called. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: What's the link to `vue-menu` (github, npm, etc)?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to see the actual code you tried in the lifecycle methods.

Comment: `{{ $route.name }}`?

Comment: please can you reproduce the problem on jfiddle and post the link here ?

Comment: @Phil `{{$route.name}}` did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the "watch"

```js
data() {
    return {
        routeName: null,
    };
},

watch: {
    '$route': 'currentRoute'
},

methods: {
    currentRoute() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.routeName = this.$route.name
        });
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
export default {
  computed:{
     routeName(){
       return this.$route.name
    },
  }
};
</script>
<template>
  <p>Current Route is {{$route.name}}</p>
</template>
```

-------------------OR--------------

```
<script>
    export default {
      computed:{
         routePath(){
           return this.$route.path 
        },
      }
    };
    </script>
    <template>
          <p>Current Route is {{$route.path}}</p>
        </template>
```

This answer is for vue2.

Also, created lifecycle can also be used by directly returning the route example below

```
created() {
    return this.$route.name
  },
```